# Static objects in activity not accessable from service :(

Tags: android, object, service, android-activity, static

I have a problem: I want to use static objects in several activites and a service (in an extra process). Unfortunately the service does not get the objects from the activity and vice versa.
I try to simplify where I think is my problem in code samples:

Activity "main":

```
public static myObject o1;
public static myObject o2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     o1 = new myObject("someParameter");
}
```

Service "myService":

```
private myObject o1;
private myObject o2;

public void onCreate() {
   this.o1 = main.o1;
   this.o2 = main.o2;

   this.o2 = new myObject("someOtherParameter");
}
```

Now the problem: for the main-activity (and all other activites) o2 is always null (although set with the service).
For the service o1 is always null (although set in main) :(
But if I understood Java-Objects correctly this *should* not be the case, am I right?

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: When are you starting your service and your activity. Are you sure that the activity is started before the service ?

Comment: This isn't a great way to do things. I don't have a specific answer for you, but you should pass objects directly via methods.

Comment: Also be very careful what are you doing. Static members can cause memory leaks in your application - for more info check http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: main activity start the myService activity?

Comment: ok, although I made a few mistakes in the sample code I wrote, I now know what the REAL issue is: the service runs in a different process and therefore cannot access the same variables (even a Singleton-pattern doesn't work because it returns different instances) -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with Java but with Android. Android doesn't allow you to access variables of a different process. Just remove the android:process attribute from the service in the manifest file So that the service runs in the same process in which your activity is running.

Answer (score 0):

you can add modifier static to o1,o2 from service class , but you can use directly the ones from main why do you want to make copy? Using static objects in android helps to cache and is good to keep them just in one class

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because you're setting `this.o2` to a new reference to an object.  In this program you have four references and two objects.

```
main.o1 -> OBJECT1
main.o2 -> NULL
```

At beginning of the program.

On line `this.o2 = main.o2`, you are setting `this.o2` as a reference to `main.o2`.  So now you have:

```
this.o2 -> main.o2 -> NULL
```

On line `this.o2 = new myObject("Something");`, `this.o2` is now referencing a new object all-together.  This gives you:

```
this.o2 -> OBJECT2
main.o2 -> NULL
```

Change the last line to `main.o2 -> new myObject("Something");` you'll get:

```
this.o2 -> main.o2 -> OBJECT2
```

Please note, this is all considered bad coding practice.  You never want to change a static variable from a class.  Also, in Android, you generally don't want to access the call of an activity directly like this.

Answer (score 0):

As DeeV says, using statics this way is not great practice but if you **absolutely** have to do it then putting them in your Application class contains the mess to some extent.

Classes derived from Context (e.g. Service and Activity) support the getApplication() or getApplicationContext() method which you have to cast to your application class to access the variables.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
       public static myObject o1; 
       public static myObject o2; 
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
       public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
              myObject o1 = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).o1;
              }
}

public class MyService extends Service {
       public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
              myObject o2 = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).o2;
              }
}
```

Bear in mind that you will have to synchronize access to the variables from different threads.